# Mann-Kendall's trend test result

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, p-value, kendall-tau, test-for-trend

I'm running the [Mann-Kendall](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/trend/vignettes/trend.pdf) trend test on my data (35 different vectors, 5 elements each). What I'm doing for each one is:

```
install.packages("Kendall")
library("Kendall")
x=c(170.192, 179.397, 171.199, 108.399, 144.964)
MannKendall(x)
```

where x is a sample vector. I'm getting a result:

```
tau = -0.4, 2-sided pvalue =0.46243
```

Now, my question is – is it believable if I obtain exactly the same result for other vectors? For example:

```
y=c(2.63075, 2.01657, 1.39161, 2.51637, 1.79445)
MannKendall(y)
tau = -0.4, 2-sided pvalue =0.46243

z=c(7.12617, 6.01319, 4.64843, 6.42136, 5.36868)
MannKendall(z)
tau = -0.4, 2-sided pvalue =0.46243
```

Is it about the data type or I'm doing/interpreting something wrong? Or maybe it's ok and I shouldn't worry?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you counted the numbers of increases in each of the vectors `x`, `y`, `z`?  Since none of them contains any ties, the M-K test depends only on the vector lengths (which are all $5$) and the numbers of increases.

Comment: your code doesn't run; MannKendall is not a function in R. ... What did you leave out?

Comment: @Glen_b you need to install package Kendall to run this function

Comment: You should edit your question to say so. If you include code, people should be able to copy it and run it and have it work (i.e. examples should be [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test statistic will be obtained by calculating the Kendall correlation of the time series with the sequence $1,2,...,n$. Getting identical Kendall correlations with very small samples is not a surprise.

When there's no ties, this correlation corresponds to counting the number of increases (times $y_j>y_i$ when $j>i$) minus number of decreases (times $y_j<y_i$ when $j>i$) divided by number of such pairs.

Your 3 sets of ranks are

```
rank(x);rank(y);rank(z)
[1] 3 5 4 1 2
[1] 5 3 1 4 2
[1] 5 3 1 4 2
```

the last two sets are identical, so the Kendall correlation for z must be the same as for y. Let's just look at the first two, then. "3 5 4 1 2" has 3 increases (3 vs 5, 3 vs 4 and 1 vs 2) and the rest are decreases. "5 3 1 4 2" has 3 increases (3 vs 4, 1 vs 4 and 1 vs 2) with the rest decreases. This means the Kendall correlation with time in each case is $(3 - 7)/10 = -0.4$

... which is what your test says they are; the p-values are then the same because the sample sizes are the same.